# Highlight all non localized texts in ASP.Net MVC markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

Currently I am working on a large ASP.Net MVC application and we support localization for 5 different languages. While developing the code we generally write the English text along within the markup, later we move this to corresponding .resx files.

But sometimes it is getting missed while move the strings from each file. `Is there a way to highlight all non-localized text in the .cshtml file?`

e.g: `<div> <p>First Name</p> </div>` - here First Name is not localized. I need to highlight all such strings. Not only in markup but in scripts also.

Answer (score -1):

In one case (javascript) i made all localized strings CAPITAL. 
All string that remain normal were either variables or not translated.

Not sure in something like this is supported in MVC.